# Pandas DataFrame with Special Characters to LaTeX Table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to:

1. Create a Pandas DataFrame with special characters (i.e., ñ,ê)
2. Convert this DataFrame to a LaTeX table

Both of these tasks seem to be problematic in Python2. Traditionally, in a table without special characters, I would use the `.to_latex()` function to convert the DataFrame to LaTeX.

Initial attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3],"b": ['abc','def','ñê']})
df.to_latex()

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file test.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: Is this Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @JohanL Python2. Unfortunately I need to get it to work in that. Updated the question. Seems to work fine in Python3.

Comment: Works for me in an interactive Python 2.7.16 REPL using Pandas 0.24.2 with the output: `u'\\begin{tabular}{lrl}\n\\toprule\n{} &  a &    b \\\\\n\\midrule\n0 &  1 &  abc \\\\\n1 &  2 &  def \\\\\n2 &  3 &   \xf1\xea \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'`